# How to calculate the rotation matrix for pitch, roll and azimuth?

Tags: math, matrix, geometry, rotation

I am working on a gradiometer, which measures the gradient of the magnitude of the magnetic field.
This gradiometer uses a two-axis tild sensor to measure the pitch and roll angles and a magnetic compass to measure the azimuth angle. The pitch is counted positively when the gradiometer points its nose upwards. The roll is counted positively when the gradiometer tilts to port side. The heading is counted from the north, positively when the gradiometer turns to the east.
Writing p,r,h the pitch, roll and heading/azimuth, I would like to calculate the rotation matrix to pass from the reference frame attached to the gradiometer to the UTM (easting, northing and vertical) coordinates, in terms of p, r, h.
Any advice?

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here, since it's not a specific programming question; try math.stackexchange.com. That said, my advice is to construct separate rotation matrices for each part (pitch, roll, heading), and multiply them together.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. But in what order do I have to multiply them ? The multiplication with matrix is not commutative.

Comment: I don't know off hand; I think that's an important question that you could investigate. I think a web search will find some resources.